# Substring a variable with two percent in a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, ms-dos

I faced a problem trying to implement a .bat file and I didn't find an answer.
I try to display all folder names without the system path.

I've tried something like that but it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
for /d %%I in (C:\test\test*) do (
    cd %%I 2>&1 >nul
    echo %%~nxI:~10,5
)
cd %back% 2>&1 >nul
```

Do you have a solution please ? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.
Here is a solution that worked for me :

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /d %%I in (C:\test\testV*) do (     
    set current_folder=%%I
    set test_version=!current_folder:~12,6!
    set test_version=!test_version:_=.!

    echo !current_folder!
    echo !test_version!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Substrings do only work with normal variables, not the for meta variables.
Copy content to a var and as this is inside a (code block) you need [DelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
Using the pseudo call method:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\26\SU_1345000.cmd
@echo off
PushD .
for /d %%I in (A:\test\test*) do (
    Set "Dir=%%I"
    Call echo %%Dir:~10,5%%
)
PopD
```

In a tree like this:

```
> tree 
└───test
    ├───test1
    ├───test2
    └───test3
```

that returns

```
> Q:\Test\2018\07\26\SU_1345000.cmd
st1
st2
st3
```

Possibly your offset wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dir /ad /b C:\test\test*`

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
for /d %%I in (C:\test\test*) do (
    dir /ad /b %%I
)
cd %back% 2>&1 >nul
```

This script would print all folder names in the folders `C:\test\test*`